# Connecting to SQL2008R2 from LightSwitch

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-lightswitch, sql-server-2008r2-express

I'm trying to build my first lightswitch application against a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.  I have sqlexpress running also (once I found out it was required for development).  The search screen that gets generated against a simple table does not show any data and instead gives the tooltip message "Unable to load data. Please check your network connection".  I can query the relevant table from within VisualStudio 2010SP1 TransactSQL Editor without any problems.  Running on Windows7.  Anyone have any idea what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any periods in your table names?  It looks like LS replaces periods with underscores in table names (probably other things as well, but this was my find).  I had a table with a period in the name.  I renamed the table, replacing the period with an underscore, updated the project and suddenly everything worked fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

see:
[Troubleshooting LightSwitch Beta 2 Setup and Configuration Issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/7ca9ddf6-27da-487d-8383-d8dad3a612ca)